# How to override a parent's class extension with child definition in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, swiftui, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a base `Node` class that can be extended with inheritance via a composable set of protocols to add additional features conditionally to the base `Node` class. To start, I'm adding a `Previewable` protocol that can extend a `Node` to provide an optional preview view to some implementation.

Self contained example:

```
import SwiftUI

// MARK: Base node protocol

protocol Node: AnyObject {
    var name: String { get }
}

extension Node {
    var name: String {
        get { "Unnamed Node" }
    }
}

// MARK: Previewable node

protocol Previewable {
    associatedtype PreviewBody: SwiftUI.View
    
    @ViewBuilder var previewBody: Self.PreviewBody { get }
}

extension Node {
    var previewBody: some View {
        Text("No Preview")
    }
}

// MARK: Test node impl

class TestNode: Node, Previewable {
    typealias PreviewView = Text
    
    var name: String = "Test Node"
    
    var previewBody: some View {
        Text("Test Preview")
    }
}

// MARK: Test content view

struct NodeView<NodeType: Node>: View {
    var node: NodeType
    
    init (_ node: NodeType) {
        self.node = node
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            node.previewBody
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var node = TestNode()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NodeView(node)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

My assumption was that the `previewBody` implementation on the `TestNode` type would override the `Node` extension that returns `No Preview` by default. However when I'm running this, I'm seeing `"No Preview"` instead of the `"Test Preview"` text provided by the class implementation.

I'm getting a feeling that I'm tackling this the wrong way but I'm not entirely sure how to correct it. Ideally I'd like the `Previewable` type to be implemented in a way that `Node` inheriting types can be checked for optional compliance when they're displayed. I can't figure out a way to do it though without generics (i.e. in the `NodeView` struct) that would allow `NodeView` to just take a generic node as an argument (later I need a method of passing an array of `[any Node]` to a view to display them all depending on what protocols they implement, so generics in this case isn't ideal).

How can I update this better conform to Swift semantics and make it correctly display the implementation's `"Test Preview"` view and not the extension's default `"No Preview"` view?

Comment: Methods on protocols aren't dynamically dispatched unless they're requirements on the protocol themselves. I.e. you'd need to define `var previewBody: some View { get }` inside the protocol. That gets complex though, because you'll need to use an associated type instead of `some View`, and it all kinda falls apart. What are you actually trying to do with all this?

Comment: @Alexander The end goal is be able to have several types of `Node`s (some of which support preview views and some which don't) that can all be passed to a generic array (i.e. `[any Node]`) and have all of them dynamically displayed in a `View` depending on whether they support previews (or other future features) or not

Comment: Your design is kind of weird - a `NodeView` should require the `NodeType` to be both a `Node` *and* `Previewable` right? I understand that some nodes may not have a `previewBody`, but it is the job of `Previewable`, not `Node`, to provide a default preview body. Does that make sense?

Comment: @KeithM How is a `Node` different from SwiftUI's `View`? In any case, if you want `[any Node]` to work, you'll end up needing to use `AnyView` to abstract over the differences between the concrete types, which might not be something you want to do

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah makes sense! One part of my design I left out for brevity is that every `Node` also provides a SwiftUI `View` that's displayed by `NodeView` along with the optional `previewView` if the `Node` is `Previewable` so I'll think about how that can apply to it.

Comment: @Alexander I've been thinking `AnyView` is probably what I'll need to use, but I've been told before not to use it if I absolutely don't need to because of performance impacts so I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something first. I expect that's probably what I'll end up having to use to make it work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexander stated in the comments,

> Methods on protocols aren't dynamically dispatched unless they're requirements on the protocol themselves.

When you do `node.previewBody`, Swift only knows that `node` is some `Node`. The only thing called `previewBody` declared on `Node` is the one with the `Text("No Preview")`. The `Text("Test Preview")` one is declared in `TestNode`, and Swift doesn't know that `node` is `TestNode` at compile time.

Compare this to when you access `node.name`, which *is* dispatched dynamically. There are two things called `name` declared on `Node` - the property requirement and the default implementation that returns `"Unnamed Node"`. Swift picks the former so that at runtime, it is dynamically dispatched to the witness of the protocol requirement.

I think your design would make more sense if `Previewable` provided the default implementation anyway:

```
extension Previewable {
    var previewBody: Text {
        Text("No Preview")
    }
}
```

And since `NodeView` uses `previewBody`, it should require that the `NodeType` be both a `Node` *and* `Previewable`.

```
struct NodeView<NodeType: Node & Previewable>: View {
```